# How to split table up into multiple tables with unique rows based on sku

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with tier pricing showing the more products purchased the better the price.

I have to import this table into another program that only lets me import products with the same sku once. This means I have to split the csv and export it into multiple csv's.

Below is example of my table however my actual table has a lot more results/rows.

| sku | qty | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 15 | 10.00 |
| abc | 10 | 8.00 |
| abc | 5 | 7.00 |
| xyz | 10 | 5.00 |
| bbb | 8 | 3.50 |
| xxx | 14 | 27.00 |
| xxx | 12 | 20.50 |
| xxx | 10 | 15.50 |
| xxx | 8 | 10.00 |

I would say the maximum amount of tiers is 4 like sku 'xxx' so this would mean I would need a total of 4 statements.

I am struggling how to work out and split up the data into 4 separate tables.

I did try adding a row_number function and then thought maybe I could just export the odd/even row_numbers but that wouldn't work when working with qty's more than 2.

Is there another MySQL function I have not found yet that can perform this task?

The end result I am trying to achieve is like this with 4 statements for each tier.

| sku | qty | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 15 | 10.00 |
| xyz | 10 | 5.00 |
| bbb | 8 | 3.50 |
| xxx | 14 | 27.00 |

| sku | qty | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 10 | 8.00 |
| xxx | 12 | 20.50 |

| sku | qty | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 5 | 7.00 |
| xxx | 10 | 15.50 |

| sku | qty | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | 8 | 10.00 |

here is the db-fiddle with the row_number added.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ofmx1KCHBjpRhHLonjkReq/0

any help appreciated. thankyou

Comment: Are you indeed using MySQL 5.7? Or can you use 8.0?

Comment: MariaDB 10.3.38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this `row_number()` function works in MySQL 8.0 and I believe works in your version of MariaDB. Try running just the CTE part of the query first to ensure it's compatible and to better understand how that function works.

```
with tiers as (
  select sku, qty, price, 
    row_number() over (partition by sku order by qty desc) as rn
  from orders_details
  )
select sku, qty, price
from tiers
where rn = 1 --repeat for 2, 3 and 4, each separately
```

Answer (score 1):

Even in old Mysq or Maroadb version can this be achieved

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
       IF(sku = @sku, @rownum := @rownum + 1, @rownum := 1) AS `rank'`,
          @sku := sku as sku,
       t.qty,t.price
  FROM (SELECT * FROM orders_details ORDER BY sku,qty DESC LIMIT 18446744073709551615) t, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0, @sku := '') r
ORDER BY 1;
```

| rank' | sku | qty | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 15 | 10 |
| 1 | xyz | 10 | 5 |
| 1 | bbb | 8 | 4 |
| 1 | xxx | 14 | 27 |
| 2 | abc | 10 | 8 |
| 2 | xxx | 12 | 21 |
| 3 | xxx | 10 | 16 |
| 3 | abc | 5 | 7 |
| 4 | xxx | 8 | 10 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ofmx1KCHBjpRhHLonjkReq/1)